# SQL Check if a "CHECK CONSTRAINT" has been ran?

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table

Should the second `ALTER TABLE` `CHECK CONSTRAINT` be in an `IF (NOT) EXISTS` so that the script can be executed repeatedly?

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS 
    WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME ='fk_RoleId'
)
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY([RoleId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[webpages_Roles] ([RoleId])
END
GO

-- Put me in an IF ... () BEGIN ... END?
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_RoleId]
GO
```

It doesn't cause any errors, but if it should be in an `IF` clause, how do you test if it has been ran (what can the if contain)?

Comment: The second step is redundant. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529941/whats-the-difference-between-with-check-add-constraint-followed-by-check-constr

Answer (score 1):

If you do want a check (it's not necessary), [`sys.foreign_keys`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189807.aspx) has a column `is_not_trusted`:

> FOREIGN KEY constraint has not been verified by the system.