# Change column to foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I change an existing column from `bit` to a foreign key (`int`)?

For example, column `NEW_B` was created like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[APPLICATION]
ADD [NEW_B] [bit] NULL
GO
```

But now I want the `NEW_B` to reference column `ID` (int) of table `ATTACHMENT` (want to keep the name `NEW_B`, also allow `NULLs`).

Comment: First alter table and set the column type to int, then add a foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the syntax:

```
--alter existing column to int
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[APPLICATION] ALTER COLUMN [NEW_B] INT NULL
GO

--add foreign key constraint
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[APPLICATION] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_APPLICATION_ATTACHMENT] FOREIGN KEY([NEW_B])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ATTACHMENT] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[APPLICATION] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_APPLICATION_ATTACHMENT]
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please also explain what the `WITH CHECK` is doing (I guess you can not reference non-existent IDs ?) and why the 3rd statement (`... CHECK CONSTRAINT ...`) is needed?

Comment: You can skip the last check. It is generated by `ssms`. You can read about this for example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529941/with-check-add-constraint-followed-by-check-constraint-vs-add-constraint

Comment: Found the answers [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24297/alter-table-check-constraint). In my particular case I will use `WITH NOCHECK`.