# What is the purpose of including CHECK CONSTRAINT & GO in the generated database schema script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on SDL Server 2008 R2, where I generated a schema-only database script. The generated script is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ConsoleServer]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ConsoleServer_RackUnits] FOREIGN KEY([RackUnitID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[RackUnits] ([UnitID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ConsoleServer] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ConsoleServer_RackUnits]
```

I have these 2 questions:-

- I know that the first line is responsible to create a FK between two DB tables. but what is the purpose of the following :

  `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ConsoleServer] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ConsoleServer_RackUnits]`
- In general, why does the DB script have the word `GO`. Now if I remove it the script will be executed well on the destination DB, so why it is included in the script prior to any statement?

Comment: Your first question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/530303/2091410). As for the `GO`, it's answered well [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20711373/2091410). The GO statement isn't needed for your situation. It's just a case of SSMS being extra careful when emitting the SQL commands because it doesn't know what the *next* command will be.

Comment: @EdGibbs and what about the "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ConsoleServer] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ConsoleServer_RackUnits]" ? do i need it ,, since i am creating a constraint with Check in the later table ?

Comment: I don't think you do. It would make sense if the constraint was initially defined `WITH NOCHECK`, but it wasn't. Just another case I think of SSMS being overly cautious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The `ALTER TABLE ... CHECK CONSTRAINT ...` line enables the constraint. You can add a constraint and leave it disable (while you clean up the data for example). See more [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24297/alter-table-check-constraint)
2. `GO` is a batch separator, it's only recognized by SSMS. Some statements, such as `CREATE PROCEDURE...` requires it to be the first statement in the batch. You can type it out in a new file, or use `GO` to terminate the previous batch. Don't send `GO` from your application through OLEDB or ADO.NET though.

Comment: so in my case as i specify to create the constraint "with check" in the alter statment,,, do i still need the second statment ?

Comment: so why sql server management studio specify this when i generate a schema only script for the table ? is there a reason for this ?

Comment: I guess you use the Create Script feature from the contextual menu. SSMS **always** does that. You would also notice that it puts everything in square brackets, like `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[my_table]`. Microsoft chose to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

According to a "reasonably consistent" chat with chatgpt 3.5, when you create a new fk it is enabled by default, so the following check constraint is redundant (not necessary), but I assume it is included as a... formality? protocol? I'm not sure, just guessing it.